Making source language books available in destination language, independently, of publisher, electronically
Nowadays it is possible to purchase some (but not all) books, that are available in paper format, in electronic format.
For instance, one may use Google Play Books or Amazon Kindle, to read, books (digitally, electronically).
However, now suppose a book is available in a source language, but one wants to read it in a destination language (and the publisher has, alas, unfortunately, for the reader, not made a translation available, digitally.
Translation services that are free of charge include ChatGPT, although people may also use stuff like Reverso (or, Google Translate).
However, these require cutting and pasting of text.
With electronic versions of books, this may not always be possible (for instance the punishers, and  perhaps, the reading media (?app, may disallow cutting and pasting, (or any modification of the text (including, translation?).
So, I was wondering, after purchasing a book or reading a free one, is, it, at all possible, to read a translation, automatically?
I am looking for a sort of service where the ebook reader makes a translation available, even, dynamically, by connecting to ChatGPT, storing the reading language in the preference (the reader will have a list of books you are browsing, and each book with have associated preference, and book annotation settings), and storing the translated content locally on the smartphone for ease of reference, and speed.
Is this at all done or work in progress?
Is anyone willing to implement this?
Would the main players be the ones mentioned?
When, will I be able, to use, and access, this feature / service?
Thanks.
